# Locked out of Heroku bc MFA

Tags: heroku

Heroku stopped allowing SMS and I didn't have recovery codes and I got a new phone so my authentication app got reset. Is there a way to access my Heroku Dashboard?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because [customer service questions are off-topic here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/354577). Please contact Heroku.

Comment: This is a perfectly legitimate question.  It's not about if customer service is available or not.  It's about leveraging the collective knowlege of our community.

Answer (score 0):

You can read [their help article on what to do in this situation](https://help.heroku.com/7IDU8QZZ/what-should-i-do-if-i-m-locked-out-of-my-heroku-account). If you have any cookies for heroku.com on your browser, you may need to open the link in an incognito tab (Don't ask me why, I am just the messenger).